# Altair Area Chart Doesn't Display Properly (though It looks fine as a Bar Chart)

Tags: altair

I'm not able to identify why the first half of my [area chart](https://ibb.co/gMsNd97) looks so unusual, while a [bar chart](https://ibb.co/098tcB8) of the same dataset looks completely normal.

Here is the dataframe data in csv format:

```
Month,Poll_Num
SEP,29.7
AUG,28.8
JUL,29.9
JUN,30.3
MAY,35.9
APR,32.2
MAR,30.6
FEB,28.5
JAN,29.9
DEC,22.2
NOV,27.2
```

I used the following code to plot this data as a bar chart:

```
alt.Chart(dataframe).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('Month', sort=list(dataframe.Month)),
    y=alt.Y('Poll_Num'))
```

To create the area chart from the same dataframe, all I did was call the mark_area() method instead of mark_bar()

```
alt.Chart(dataframe).mark_area().encode(
    x=alt.X('Month', sort=list(dataframe.Month)),
    y=alt.Y('Poll_Num'))
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong, or what's causing this unusual looking area chart?

Comment: When I run your code I get a normal area chart. Can you describe what you're seeing, and how it's different than what you'd like to see?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @jakevdp. The output I'm seeing is the image in [this link](https://ibb.co/gMsNd97). Unfortunately I couldn't post it directly here b/c I don't have a high enough point ranking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to you rendering your chart with an older version of vega-lite – the bug was fixed in vega-lite 3.4. The incorrect version of the chart, rendered with Vega-Lite 3.3 or older, looks like this:

[image]

The correct version of the chart, rendered with Vega-Lite 3.4 or newer, looks like this:

[image]

To fix it, make certain your frontend renderer is up-to-date. How to do this depends on what frontend you are using:

- For *JupyterLab*: update to the most recent version of JupyterLab (the vega-lite renderer is bundled with it)
- For *Jupyter Notebook*: update the `vega` package to the most recent version (`pip install -U vega`).
- For *Colab*, *Kaggle*, or Altair's built-in `serve()` method: make certain you are using Altair version 3.2 or newer (`pip install -U altair`).

Comment: I appreciate your help, @jakevdp. I updated JupyterLab and the problem persisted, unfortunately. However, I noticed that the chart displays normally if I remove the sort parameter in alt.X. I tried sorting another way via: `scale=alt.Scale(domain=['SEP', 'AUG', 'JUL', 'JUN', 'MAY', 'APR', 'MAR', 'FEB', 'JAN', 'DEC', 'NOV']) ` This produced the same output. After searching for a bit, it seems there isn't a way to assign the month names as the x-axis labels via mapping (if I were to create another column w/ month names in number format), right? That's the only solution I could think of

Comment: Ah, it looks like the newest version of the JupyterLab renderer [still uses Vega-Lite 3.3](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/105f7afd0f5789642fc41352bd9b1ec523f0322f/packages/vega5-extension/package.json#L48), so there is no way to see the correct chart in JupyterLab at the moment, unfortunately. Until JupyterLab is updated, I would suggest using another frontend, like Jupyter Notebook, Colab, or Kaggle.

Comment: Ok, I see. It does in fact work in Jupyter Notebook. Thanks again @jakevdp for your help!